# Add leading zeroes to a string

Tags: java, string

I want to add some leading zeroes to a string, the total length must be eight characters. For example:

123 should be 00000123
1243 should be 00001234
123456 should be 00123456
12345678 should be 12345678

What's the easiest way?

Comment: You seem to mean "leading zeroes", not trailing.

Answer (score 36):

A cheesy little trick

```
String str = "123";
String formatted = ("00000000" + str).substring(str.length())
```

If you started with a number instead:

```
Int number = 123;
String formatted = String.format("%08d", number);
```

Comment: the cheesy little trick is worth remembering for lots of different languages - sql dialects you don't use often for example

Comment: The first example is nice at first but it breaks if the original number is longer than 8 digits. Furthermore, if you do `("00000000" + number)` with number being an integer or long it will provide you with a string as a result. But the second option will be safer.

Answer (score 30):

Use `String.format()`, it has a specifier for that already:

```
String.format("%08d", myInteger);
```

More generally, see the javadoc for [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). It has a lot of neat stuff -- more than you can see at a first glance.

Comment: It wouldn't work with strings because the padding will be spaces.

Comment: Well, yeah, OK, not exactly like it does for numbers

Comment: Bingo.   That is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 11):

Using apache common langs lib:

```
StringUtils.leftPad(str, 8, '0');
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Using [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
static public void main(String[] args) {
    int vals[] = {123, 1243, 123456, 12345678};
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("00000000");
    for (int val : vals) {
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(val));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
00000123
00001243
00123456
12345678
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not make a simple padding function? I know there are libraries, but this is a very simple task.

```
System.out.println(padStr(123, "0", 8));
System.out.println(padStr(1234, "0", 8));
System.out.println(padStr(123456, "0", 8));
System.out.println(padStr(12345678, "0", 8));       

public String padStr(int val, String pad, int len) {
  String str = Integer.toString(val);
  while (str.length() < len)
    str = pad + str;
  return str;
}
```

Comment: This will produce a new StringBuilder and a new String on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String stringForTest = "123";
    int requiredLengthAfterPadding = 8;
    int inputStringLengh = stringForTest.length();
    int diff = requiredLengthAfterPadding - inputStringLengh;
    if (inputStringLengh < requiredLengthAfterPadding)
    {
        stringForTest = new String(new char[diff]).replace("\0", "0")+ stringForTest;
    }
    System.out.println(stringForTest);
}
```